# What's wrong with the trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

Five days ago I noticed that my calculator broke. (At least I thought)

I noticed because in school we got tought the sinus and cosinus theorem. And I evaluated the sin of a 60 and got a negative result. The result was a negative fraction above -1. But I knew that the sin function always returns a positive result.

So I came to the conclusion that my calculator is most likely broken.

Today I had to solve another equation and used Mathway for that because my calculator doesn't give me the correct results. And than somehting really strange happended when I put in this term (it's already simplyfied):

$$α=cos^{-1}(⁡\frac{97}{110})=0.4910924821$$

That can't be true either. To prove this I used the Windows build-in calculator and it gave me a plausible result. Approxmately `65°`.

Now I was interested if the result of Mathway matches the result of my calculator. And it did.

This blew my mind. How can that be that my calculator suddendly stopped working and a big Math website gets it wrong too?

Because I don't have alot of expertise in advanced maths (eg. the real algorithm behind sin, cos, tan) I wanted to share this with you guys: Does somebody know what causes this to happen and how to fix it? If you don't belive me just put the equation from above in Mathway and convice yourself (https://www.mathway.com/)

Here are a few probes:

#### My calculator

1. $sin(90)=0.8939966636$
2. $sin(60)=-0.3048106211$
3. $sin(0)=0$
4. $sin(1)=0.8414709848$
5. $cos(90)=-0.4480736161$
6. $cos(60)=-0.9524129804$
7. $cos(0)=1$
8. $cos(1)=0.5403023059$
9. $tan(90)=-1.995200412$
10. $tan(60)=0.3200403894$
11. $tan(0)=0$
12. $tan(1)=1.557407725$

#### Mathway

1. $sin(90)=1$
2. $sin(60)=0.86602540$
3. $sin(0)=0$
4. $sin(1)=0.01745240$
5. $cos(90)=0$
6. $cos(60)=0.5$
7. $cos(0)=1$
8. $cos(1)=0.99984769$
9. $tan(90)=undefined$
10. $tan(60)=1.73205080$
11. $tan(0)=0$
12. $tan(1)=0.01745506$

#### Windows Calculator

1. $sin(90)=1$
2. $sin(60)=0.86602540378443864676372317075294$
3. $sin(0)=0$
4. $sin(1)=0.01745240643728351281941897851632$
5. $cos(90)=0$
6. $cos(60)=0.5$
7. $cos(0)=1$
8. $cos(1)=0.99984769515639123915701155881391$
9. $tan(90)=Invalid input$
10. $tan(60)=1.7320508075688772935274463415059$
11. $tan(0)=0$
12. $tan(1)=0.01745506492821758576512889521973$

As for so far everything seems that just my calculator is broken right? But watch what happens when I put in things like this

#### My calculator

1. $cos^{-1}(0.2)=1.369438406$
2. $cos^{-1}(97/110)=0.4910924821$
3. $sin^{-1}(0.2)=0.213579208$

#### Mathway

1. $cos^{-1}(0.2)=1.36943840$
2. $cos^{-1}(97/110)=0.49109248$
3. $sin^{-1}(0.2)=0.20135792$

#### Windows Calculator

1. $cos^{-1}(0.2)=286.47947934265595996838245292511$
2. $cos^{-1}(97/110)=64.977160500115227146171035685935$
3. $sin^{-1}(0.2)=1.0000060923793264782497287721127$

Mathway matches the wrong answers with my calculator!

I just want to point out that my calculator has been working for ever correctly until now. It's a TI-82 Stats. Resetting and reinserting batteries didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Your calculator has at least two angle modes.  You seem to want to use degrees but your calculator is set to "radians."  Mathways works in radians also.

Comment: Oh thank you. That makes a lot of sense. Does Mathway then use degree for the normal trigonometric functions and radians for the reversed?

Comment: @B.Goddard has already answered your question.I wanted to point out that ". But I knew that the sin function always returns a positive result...." isn't true.

Comment: @BierDav: I think so. I've never heard of this website before, so I assume I'm working with default settings, and when I went on and typed in $\sin(90)$ and $\arcsin(1)$ I got respectively $1$ [which is true when the input angle is in degrees] and $\pi/2$ [which is the correct output angle in radians].

Comment: @RamanujanXV also in degree mode?